# Proving for someone that "Clothes don't present me"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositional-phrases, comparison

I want to defend my dress by saying that clothes (in general) don't present me, but after that, I want to support that sentence by adding one of these two:

1. I'm a lot bigger than a piece of cloth to show it.

OR

2. I have a lot in myself for a piece of cloth to show it.

Which one of those two is the better one for showing the real meaning that I intend?

Note: I'm not advanced at English, that's why I can't tell which one better presents what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but neither of your sentences is good English. I understand what you are trying to say but the infnitive part of the verb (to show) is used incorrectly.

You *could* rewrite the first sentence as

> "I'm a lot bigger than a piece of cloth can show"

and the second as

> "I have too much in myself for a piece of cloth to show".

You could also say

> "There's more to me than can be shown by a piece of cloth"

However none of these sentences sound like 'normal' English to me, they all sound almost poetic. I suspect that there a common sentence or proverb with this meaning in your own language which doesn't exist in English, if that's the case you can use one of the three sentences above but you need to be aware that it will sound a bit unusual to an English speaker.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. But I think the sentence you have suggested is what I was trying to form. However, I believe that you intended "than" to be "that", I guess. By the way, can I write it like this: "There's more to me that a piece of cloth can show"?

Comment: No, I meant **than**. If you said "there is more to me **that** a piece of cloth can show" you would be saying that a piece of cloth can reveal the hidden part of yourself. This is almost the opposite of what you are trying to say. Imagine someone saying "My wife and I went to India. We saw the Taj Mahal, the Golden Temple and lots of other things **that** she can tell you about. She has a better memory for details and we saw more things **than** I can remember". Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is an English saying, "**Don't judge a book by its cover**", that I believe fits what you're trying to say.

[It means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_judge_a_book_by_its_cover):

> you shouldn't prejudge the worth or value of something by its outward appearance alone.

In your case, the "outward appearance" is your clothing.

Comment: I know this saying, but it won't be suitable for my case. The person I'm talking to, knows who I am. So, we are done with the first impression thing.